# Join table or duplicate data?

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am looking for real-world implementations:
Use case is this -> I store the user login details (mode, session, browser, OS, etc) in the session table. I have a activity table where i track activities that FKs to session table.

Now when a user takes an activity on an object like "Create a photo" I want to include all the details with it like the browser the user used to upload the image, his IP address, etc. So all the fields in the session table.

On a good day you would normally FK the session_Id with the photo table and join to pull that data. But what if i duplicate the same 6-7 colunms in the photo and each object table to prevent joins/FKs?

I want to know what works in the real world on large scale user content sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not expecting the details (browser, IP address, etc) to change during a session, why duplicate the data?  Just associate each photo (or more generally, every activity instance) with the session_id that it was uploaded.

On the other hand, if you are expecting the details to change however once someone has logged in (which can occur -- think of someone having a new IP address when they login to your site on network 1, sleep their laptop, move to a new network, and then un-sleep, such that their browser retains the cookie even though the IP address changes), I would either:

- Treat those as different sessions OR
- Create a CLIENT_INFO table and make
  it a 1:M association with SESSION, so
  that you can maintain one logical
  session, but support multiple CLIENT
  instances.

If I were you, and I really needed those details, I would probably do the latter.

Comment: It wont change once logged. But the issue is then to pull the say IP address (these will be visible on the website for other people to see on page load) the system has to always join with session table to fetch the data. I am trying to prevent any joins from happening for smooth flow as joins degrade performance.

Comment: You should prefer to model it correctly before worrying about optimizing performance.  You can always cache data.  You can always create indexes.  You can always pin data in memory.  You can always buy more h/w etc to meet your performance goals.  But relating data to each other properly (per the relational model), and then leveraging that through simple join(s) should not be feared.